# Does each separate page require unique Open Graph Protocol markup or will a 'global' one suffice?

Tags: open-graph-protocol

I am in the process of integrating `og:` protocol markup to my sites and I'm wondering whether each separate page will require unique markup or whether a global one will suffice.

For instance, when implementing the standard `<meta name="description" content="">` each page will typically have a unique description.Typically, the description for the home page, for example, will be different to that of a topical internal page. Is this the same for `<meta property="og:" content="">` tags?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: Yes.

Long answer: The Open Graph tags are used to display a preview of the content on social-media sites. The better the preview of the linked content represents the actual content, the more likely it it is for users to click the link, an read the whole article on your website. (At least that's what we want).

Therefore you'll want to have a preview text representing the actual text as well as a preview image, which should be different for each page

If you don't have an image on your page, you should not use a random one from another page, as this would trick readers, which could hurt your reputation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickbait)